Explain the steps needed to solve this recurrence by guess and check method
My teacher showed us this recurrence for merge sort, and solved it using guess and check. I don't understand the steps he is taking to simplify and factor the equation.
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n
we guess that T(n) = n log n and use substitution
= 2(n/2*log n/2) + n
= n log n/2 + n
= n(log n - 1) + n --- I don't understand how we got this from the preceding line.
= n log n - n + n  --- this makes sense
= n log n          --- this makes sense
enter image description here
Here is a similar situation. How do we move from step 2 to 3?

1/ What base is the log in?  $\quad$ 2/ For the first "this makes sense", are you sure you expanded correctly? $\quad$ 3/ Basically there is an arithmetic error in the first "I don't understand", which was fixed in the next line.

Thank you for your reply! The logarithm is base 2, as this is a Computer Science course.

Apologies, you're right, I left out +n in that line. I have corrected it.

K, than what you're missing is just that $ \log (n/2) = (\log n) - (\log 2) =( \log n ) - 1$ via the rules of logarithms. (It's not clear to me which step of this breakdown you didn't understand)

Thanks, I missed that day in log class.

No guesswork, just figure it out
$$T(n)=2T\left( \frac{n}{2}\right)+n=2\cdot \left[2T\left( \frac{n}{2^2}\right)+ \frac{n}{2}\right]+n =2^2 T\left( \frac{n}{2^2}\right)+2n=\\
=2^3 T\left( \frac{n}{2^3}\right)+3n=\cdots=2^k T\left( \frac{n}{2^k}\right)+kn$$
Now taking $n=2^k$, we obtain
$$T(n)=n\Big( T(1) + \log_2 n \Big)$$
and if we have $T(1)=0$, which coincides with $\log_2 1 =0 $, then we have
$$T(n)=n\log_2 n $$
Addition.
For question with respect to image (btw its better to type it)
$$\log_2 \frac 3 2=\log_2 3 - \log_2 2 = \log_2 3 - 1$$
